# How to view native source code in browser?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototype

I am trying to manually copy some native code into our application to improve compatibility with Internet Explorer. From the Chrome console:

```
[].find.toString();
```

Outputs:

> "function find() { [native code] }"

I want to put into my application:

```
Array.prototype.find = "native code here";
```

So we can use functions like these that aren't supported in Internet Explorer. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't. That code depends on the browser. Instead you can use helpers like jQuery or Modernizer or similar libraries which provides fallback/polyfills

Comment: In this context, `[native code]` means native to the browser, which might be anything (maybe C++), but probably isn't ECMAScript. If you're looking for a [*polyfill for Array.prototype.find*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill), see [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `[native code]` are stored in browser, they are even not JavaScript.
Engine may take control when `find()` be called.

Instead, You should Search `Array.find shim` In Google.
https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&safe=off&q=Array.find+shim

Comment: Can I just write my own find function that performs the same task?

Comment: See [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill), the polyfills there try to implement the ECMA-262 algorithm as closely as they can using POJS.

Comment: @wayofthefuture of course. Only when you think your code is bug free.

Comment: Your recommendation led me to this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-shim. Very nice find and very awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know where you could find the source code  for JS functions, but you could use Modernizr for new functionalities (there are things called snippets that might help you).